# How to change the value of one hex to another hex in react.js component (Simple ways)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hex

I have a colour A = #9c2aa0
 I need a colour B  = colour A + 30% black (#000000) transparency appiled  inside react components (in pseudo class)

url for code : https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy2OY.jpg

Comment: Random generator fro color code `var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);`

Comment: Please post the relevant minimal reproducible example code in your question, don’t post it somewhere else on the internet; make it easy for people to help you and you’ll get more and better answers. How to post a Stack Snippet (in your question): 
```meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/7515189```

Comment: Sry SHG21 .I paste the code in the body of the page  ,but its not taking .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try out this function,
`#9c2aa0` is your color one plus `30%` going tobe `#4dffff` get added to get you final color.

```
function addition() {
  var finalColor = (parseInt('9c2aa0', 16) + parseInt('4dffff', 16)).toString(16);
  while (finalColor.length < 6) { finalColor = '0' + finalColor; } // Zero pad.
  return finalColor;
}
```

remember 30% going to be `#4D....something` here you want black so, `#4Dffff`.